# Using C++ libgpiod to calculate interval and speed between events

Tags: c++, embedded, embedded-linux, libgpiod

I'm using `libpgid`on C++ in order to calculate RPM from GPIO events.

The idea is to read all `RISING_EDGE` events from a given GPIO line and increment a counter (pulse counter). The counter has 3 properties:

```
typedef struct counter_t
{
    unsigned long count;           // Incremented on every RISING_EDGE pulse
    unsigned long start_timestamp; // Timestamp of the first event pulse read
    unsigned long last_timestamp;  // Timestamp of the last event pulse read
}
```

So, on every event read from `gpiod` I do:

```
auto event = line.event_read();
if (event.event_type == GPIOD_LINE_EVENT_RISING_EDGE)
{
    counter->count++;
    if (counter->start_timestamp == 0) counter->start_timestamp = event.timestamp;
    counter->last_timestamp = event.timestamp;
}
```

That runs on a thread that listen for new events and updates the counter. All fine working - and I'm getting the counter being incremented properly.

My problem arise at RPM calculation.

To do it, I run another thread at a fixed interval of 100ms, that reads the counter, calculate the RPM and reset the counter, as follows:

```
void thread_loop()
{
    std::cout << "Start thread" << std::endl;

    bool first_run = true;

    while (true)
    {
        if (!first_run)
        {
            // Get interval
            unsigned long interval = counter->last_timestamp - counter->start_timestamp;

            // Calculate speed
            double speed = (counter->count / interval) * 600000000;  //calculates speed

            // Print results
            std::cout << "SPEED: " << speed << std::endl;
            std::cout << "COUNTER: " << counter->count << std::endl;
            std::cout << "COUNTER START TIMESTAMP: " << counter->start_timestamp << std::endl;
            std::cout << "COUNTER: LAST TIMESTAMP: " << counter->last_timestamp << std::endl;
            std::cout << "INTERVAL: " << interval << std::endl;

            // Reset counter
            counter->reset(); // Sets count, start_timestamp and last_timestamp to 0
        }

        first_run = false;

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }
}
```

I am getting inconsistent speeds, as for the given output:

```
SPEED: 0
COUNTER: 40
COUNTER START TIMESTAMP: 13953904635016
COUNTER: LAST TIMESTAMP: 13956976823743
INTERVAL: 3072188727
```

From my understanding, all `libgpiod` events are nanosecond based, so 3072188727 is equivalent to 3072 milliseconds, but my thread is running at 100ms intervals (I expect not exactly that value, but something around this, not 30 times). There is nothing else running in the machine, no overload on the code.

Also, the speed calculation is always zero.

I imagine there is something wrong with my understanding or conversion of the `libgpiod` conversion, but no idea what is wrong. I've searched the [`libgpiod` docs](https://libgpiod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and cannot find any detailed explanation.

So, here are my questions:

- How can I interpret the `event.timestamp` from `libgpiod`. Is it a `time_point` event? An epoch datetime? Is it an absolute date and time?
- How can I calculate the interval, in nanoseconds, between two `libgpiod` events?
- How can I convert this interval to a speed (RPM) calculation?

Comment: `counter->count / interval` is integer division. Either cast one of arguments to `double` or multiply first.

Comment: In general, Linux is not a realtime OS. Depending on expected events rate it might be not easy to get required accuracy.

Comment: `std::this_thread::sleep_for` does not guarantee that it will be *exact*. It may well sleep for (much) longer than requested. All it guarantees is that it'll sleep for *at least* as long as requested - but it can validly overshoot by 1ms, 1sec, 1hour, 1year (unlikely, but theoretically allowed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of your problem is that the documentation you reference is **libgpiod v2**, but the `line.event_read()` call you are using is from **libgpiod v1**.  And you are mixing C and C++, as **GPIOD_LINE_EVENT_RISING_EDGE** is from the C API.
You might want to pick one API and stick to it.

a) With **libgpiod v2**, you can select the clock source using [gpiod::line_settings::set_event_clock()](https://libgpiod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/classgpiod_1_1line__settings.html). By default it is [gpiod::line::clock::MONOTONIC](https://libgpiod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/namespacegpiod_1_1line.html), i.e. **CLOCK_MONOTONIC**, which is what you want for this application.  For **libgpiod v1** the clock source depends on the kernel version - it was **CLOCK_REALTIME** prior to Linux 5.7, and **CLOCK_MONOTONIC** from 5.7 onwards.

b) Given **CLOCK_MONOTONIC**, the difference between two timestamps is the interval in nanoseconds.  Using **CLOCK_REALTIME** for this application could introduce errors, as it is susceptible to corrections to system time.

c) Firstly, your multiplier is wrong.  The interval is measured in nanoseconds, so the multiplier should be 60000000000 nanoseconds/minute (6e+10), not 600000000 (6e+8).

Your interval calculation is wrong as `start_timestamp` marks the first ever interrupt, not the beginning of the interval, whereas you reset the counter every interval.

Also reading the counter, calculating, printing and then resetting the counter introduces a potential error - the count may have have incremented in the background by the other thread.  Fixing that could involve adding functions to increment and read/reset the counter, with locking to prevent the threads contending. But better to never reset the count - have the `thread_loop()` store the previous count and determine the number of new counts since the last interval.

So, to address timestamp and count issues, drop the `start_timestamp` from `struct counter_t`, and have `thread_loop()` keep a snapshot of the previous value of counter and compare it with the latest.  The difference in the count and timestamp will give you the average RPM during that interval.

Your "always zero" problem is integer math - `(counter->count / interval)`  is 0 in integer math, given `interval > count`, which it almost certainly will be.

You need to cast at least one of them to a float to enable floating point math:

```
double speed = (double(count) / interval) * 60000000000ULL;
```

Alternatively you could keep everything in integer math by rearranging the order so the numerator is larger than the denominator:

```
unsigned long speed = (count * 60000000000ULL) / interval;
```

That could be prone to overflow if count gets large, but for reasonable interrupt rates that seems unlikely.

Also note that **libgpiod v2** provides a *seqno* on the events through [gpiod::edge_event::line_seqno()](https://libgpiod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/classgpiod_1_1edge__event.html) so you don't need to maintain your own counter - just copy that one.  Using that would also correct for any lost interrupts if your app is blocked to the point that the kernel event buffer overflows.  It won't help if the interrupts arrive faster than the kernel interrupt handler can deal with them, but you aren't likely to be dealing with RPMs that high.

Finally, you don't show how you requested the line, but if you request to only receive rising edge events then there is no need to check the event type when you read the events. This [example](https://github.com/brgl/libgpiod/blob/master/bindings/cxx/examples/watch_line_rising.cpp) from **libgpiod v2** does that, and you can do similar with **v1**.

Comment: I'm using libgpio version 1.6.3, as it comes from installig libgpiod-dev on Raspi 4. My goal is to build a RPM counter for around 5000rpm. Thanks for the input, I've solved some of the problems. I will add new questions on new posts.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of issues:

1. You have not shown the declaration of `counter` but it must be declared `volatile` as it is read and written in independent execution threads.
2. It must also be protected from asynchronous changes while being non-atomically accessed.  A mutex or a spin-lock for example. Even individual members may not be atomic, for example the 64 bit `unsigned long` (on Linux) will not be atomic on a 32 bit system.
3. Linux is not a real-time OS, and there are no guarantees that your GPIO polling thread will catch all input state changes.  It may be prompted by other threads or processes for longer than the pulse period.

This last issue is clearly not the cause of the gross error you have shown, but it will result in mostly small errors some of the time, and will certainly limit the maximum RPM  that can be detected.  What is the maximum "event rate" you would expect?